# How can I tokenize entire regex in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, matching, regex-group

I'm trying to parse time strings and transcode them into an object I am gonna call `time module`. It is just a simple dictionary object with complete time disclosure.

The thing is that I have to match string consisting of a number and time unit. Currently I am trying to match this regex:
`/^(([1-9][0-9]*)(y|m|w|d|h|min|s))+$/g`.

I need it to yield every single match. So if I feed it this string: `12y12m12w12d12h12min12s` - it should return something like this array:

```
[
    '12y12m12w12d12h12min12s',    // Matching string
    '12y',
    '12',
    'y',
    '12m',
    '12',
    'm',
    '12w',
    '12',
    'w',
    '12d',
    '12',
    'd',
    '12h',
    '12',
    'h',
    '12min',
    '12',
    'min',
    '12s',
    '12',
    's',
    index: 0,
    input: '12y12m12w12d12h12min12s',
    groups: undefined
]
```

Instead, it returns only the last unit:

```
[
    '12y12m12w12d12h12min12s',       
    '12s',
    '12',
    's',
    index: 0,
    input: '12y12m12w12d12h12min12s',
    groups: undefined
]
```

Can I do this thing using `regex`? How?

Comment: Does the output array need to be in that order?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Not necessarily. I just want it to match the time. The thing is that the time module should check the time string match for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture groups only capture the **last** match.

The new [`matchAll` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) due in ES2020 (and easily polyfilled) gets you quite close if you remove the anchors and flatten the result:

```
const rex = /([1-9][0-9]*)(y|min|m|w|d|h|s)/g;
const str = "12y12m12w12d12h12min12s";
const array = [...str.matchAll(rex)].flat();
console.log(array);
```

That doesn't give you the overall whole string match (if you want it, insert in the array), but it gives you all the rest:

Live Example:

```js
const rex = /([1-9][0-9]*)(y|min|m|w|d|h|s)/g;
const str = "12y12m12w12d12h12min12s";
const array = [...str.matchAll(rex)].flat();
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If you don't want to use `matchAll`, you'll need a loop:

```
const result = [];
let match;
while ((match = rex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    result.push(...match);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const rex = /([1-9][0-9]*)(y|min|m|w|d|h|s)/g;
const str = "12y12m12w12d12h12min12s";
const result = [];
let match;
while ((match = rex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    result.push(...match);
}
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Although, I think that I'll stick to quite different approach. Because I need to match the whole string, not just part. If there is something that doesn't belong there, it needs to return `null`. The thing is I am going to use that to validate the time expression in given string. I think I'll dig out my old code that worked and integrate it in my new code. But thank you anyway :)

Comment: @Polda18 - [Trincot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60136256/157247) validates the full string, the second code snippet (as I write this comment) may be what you want.

Comment: (It doesn't include the full string in the result, but that's easily added after the check if you want it.)

Comment: @TJCrowder No, I meant that I need the entire string only match the specified time format. That being said, I don't want to have anything else in that string, therefore it returns no match if there is something that doesn't belong there. I already managed to retrieve the code (luckily, I still haven't deleted my old code yet). The regex I am going with in the end is this one: `/^(?<y>[1-9][0-9]*y)?(?<m>[1-9][0-9]*m)?(?<w>[1-9][0-9]*w)?(?<d>[1-9][0-9]*d)?(?<h>[1-9][0-9]*h)?(?<min>[1-9][0-9]*min)?(?<s>[1-9][0-9]*s?)?$/i`

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to match the whole input at once, since indeed the capture group with the `+` suffix will only capture the last match.

Instead iterate over the sub-matches. If you require that the whole string should eventually match, without any interrupting character sequences, then adapt your regex so that it also matches deviating characters in a separate capture group:

```js
let regex = /([1-9][0-9]*)(y|min|m|w|d|h|s)|(.)/g
let s = "12y12m12w12d12h12min12s";
let matches = [...s.matchAll(regex)];
console.log(matches);
```

So, the output is a 2D array, where each row has 4 elements:

1. the full match of one time unit
2. the numeric part
3. the unit part
4. if this is not `undefined`, then this row represents a character that did not match with the number-unit-pattern

Note that I moved `min` before the `m` in your regex, since you want to give precedence to a `min` match over a simple `m` match.

You can the filter that array to see if there is a non-match by that 4th value. If not, the array can be easily reduced to your sample output.

```js
let regex = /([1-9][0-9]*)(y|min|m|w|d|h|s)|(.)/g
let s = "12y12m12w12d12h12min12s";
let matches = [...s.matchAll(regex)];

if (matches.some(row => row[3])) throw "not matching completely";
matches = matches.flatMap(row => row.slice(0,3));
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: That's not really all that close to what the OP said they wanted.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thank you for your encouraging comment. The OP wrote *"something like"*. I think I met that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I see you have now adapted your answer to use (almost) the same approach that I suggest in my answer, including the flattening I had added.

Comment: @ trincot - I didn't see you'd added it. Good addition. But yes, I also thought of `matchAll`, then went with a loop, then went away and realized why `matchAll` hadn't worked for me originally (I'd removed too many capture groups), so I came back and added it. I did not copy it, as you seem to be implying. (In fact, looking at yours, they're quite different.)

Comment: I still like the additional check I did, which corresponds to the `^`  and `$` requirement that the OP's regex had. But I see they accepted your answer (even though I posted this first, but no problem), so it does not seem that important a requirement for them.